# SendKeys getting into infinite loop

Tags: wpf, winforms, winapi, wpf-controls

I am trying to write an WinForms application which simulate keyboard button clicks.I tried SendKeys.Send()/SendWait(), but, it leads to infinite loop.I tried to sleep the thread for 5 sec., but, it looped with interval of 5 sec.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SendKeys.SendWait("Hi {Enter}");
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
```

Comment: The space in that string operates the button again.  You'll need to ensure that the correct window is in the foreground.  Given that you clicked a button, right now it is *your* window that's in the foreground.  That's the wrong window.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently your `button1` has the focus after being clicked. Now sending `Enter` presses the button another time. To solve that you need to set the focus before sending keys to wherever your keys should go to (another app, another control).

Comment: Well, you're very unspecific which GUI you have (WPF, WinForms) and where your input shall go. So I would need to guess. Please have a look at the related documentation or search for "wpf textbox focus" (for instance). Usually there are some "setfocus" methods.